# Efficient way to count related entities of a many to many relation in EF

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I would like to know how to efficiently count (SQL server side) the amount of distinct count of results for a specific range of a related entity that has a many to many relationship.

This is the current situation in entity Framework:

> Table1 1<------->∞ Table2
>
> Table2 ∞<------->∞ Table4

Table 2 and Table 4 have a many to many relationship and are linked with Table3 in SQL.
What I want is the distinct count of table4 results related to a specific range of Table1.

In LinQ to SQL the query is this:

```
(from dc in Table1
join vc in Table2 on dc.Table1Id equals vc.Table2Id
join vcac in Table3 on vc.Table2Id equals vcac.Table3Id
                                join ac in Table4 on vcac.Table3Id equals ac.Table4Id 
                                where dc.Table1Id > 200000
                                group ac by ac.Table4Id into nieuw
                                select new { acid= nieuw.Key}).Count()
```

This lets SQL server return the count directly.
Because the extra table for the many to many relation ( Table3) is gone, I have had problems converting this query to L2E in query syntax. ( since I cannot join table 4 with table 2 with an inner join).

I have this in chained syntax, however, is this efficient ( does this fetch the whole list, or does it let SQLserver do the count, as I'm not sure this is an efficient way to select, Table 2 contains about 30.000 entries, I don't want it to fetch this result just to count it):

```
context.Table4.Where(a => a.Table2.Any(v => v.Table1Id > 200000)).Select(a => aTable4Id).Distinct().Count();
```

How would I go converting the Linq2SQL query into L2E in the query syntax ? Or is the chained syntax fine in this situation ?

Comment: Where are the navigation properties? (`Table1.Table2s` etc.)

Comment: In EF:
Table1.Table2
Table2.Table4
Table2.Table1
Table4.Table2
Table4.Table4

Comment: So use these in stead of `join`.

Answer (score 0):

The `.Select()` method [uses deferred execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx), meaning it won't actually run the query until you need the results.  At that point in the chain it still exists only as a query definition. Then you modify with `.Distinct()` before getting `.Count()` - which does query the database using a SQL GROUP BY statement. So you should be good.